# How to handle multi-select data for machine learning on python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, categorical-data

One of my features is from a question in the form of "select all that apply". This means each entry has multiple values separated by commas like:

[image]

and so on. I need to convert this to numerical data so I can use it for my machine learning model. Something similar to what OneHotEncoder does. How do I handle this kind of data

EDIT:

Here is what I imagine the results to look like

[image]

Comment: Could you please provide expected result? kr

Comment: @antoine I've added what I would like the results to look like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `Series.str.get_dummies` then use `DataFrame.add_prefix` to get your desired column names:

```
df['Feature'].str.get_dummies(sep=',').add_prefix('feature_')
```

```
   feature_option1  feature_option2  feature_option3  feature_option4
0                1                0                1                0
1                0                0                0                1
2                0                1                1                0
```